# Is "Заходи, покажешь X" {Imperative + Future} an equivalent of "come and show me X" {Imperative + Imperative} in English?

Tags: tense, повелительное-наклонение, будущее-время

> 1) **Заходи** как-нибудь, **покажешь** фотки! {Imperative + Future}

I'm assuming this phrase means "come and show me the photos sometime". In English, both "come" and "show" are in Imperative, while in Russian it takes the form of "Imperative + Future".

I wonder if "Заходи, покажешь X" is the construction commonly used to express the idea of "come and do something". Do the following alternatives sound odd?

> 2) **Заходи** как-нибудь, **покажи** фотки! {Imperative + Imperative}
>
> 3) **Заходи** как-нибудь **показать** фотки!  {Imperative + Infinitive} -- similar to "come to show"

---

On another note: Is it unusual to use the perfective "зайти" here?

> 4) **Зайди** как-нибудь, **покажешь** фотки! {Perfective Imperative + Perfective Future}
>
> {vs}: **Заходи** как-нибудь, **покажешь** фотки! {Imperfective Imperative + Perfective Future}

Comment: The quick answer is, 3) and 4) aren't very idiomatic, 2) is dubious, the verbs would usually be paired as follows: ***заходи + покажешь*** OR ***зайди + покажи***

Comment: Заходи как-нибудь, покажешь фотки! is similar to English 'You might (could) come some day and show me the pics. - it sounds polite in Russian, because _как-нибудь_ makes the imperative less demanding and _покажешь_ is non-imperative (i.e. not demanding).

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка 3) is a rather normal phrase, but it implies the importance of the very action of showing photos. Like in "Roman holidays" movie, when the journo visits the newspaper office exactly to present his photos to the editor. Was that not those photos - he would not have paid that visit at all. And those photos were his official job ordered. So, #3 is usually a phrase about more official, binding, obliging situations, than relaxed forms #1 and #2. But with that connotation marked, #3 IS idiomatic too.

Comment: @Arioch it's certainly understandable and grammatically sound, but i personally wouldn't use it, it doesn't ring smooth to me

Comment: Matter of taste. To me it sounds less casual and more strained, but still quite usable. There surely is a difference in intonations, but it not that much that I would care in everyday life. For example if me with some mate just was making those photos (to the old film camera) and he would have the film to print photos from later, then, immediately after the shooting, I would probably use #3 phrase. Depends on personal habits and many nuances

Answer (score 3):

> I'm assuming this phrase means "come and show me the photos sometime"

Your assumption is correct.

> I wonder if "Заходи, покажешь X" is the construction commonly used...

Yes, it is quite a usual way to say this.

> Do the following alternatives sound odd?

`Заходи как-нибудь, покажи фотки!`
I can think of a situation wherein someone would use these words, but it would be most likely without `как-нибудь`, but with `сейчас/сегодня/через час` as the second imperative makes it like the action should not be in an uncertain future, but soon. But overall I would not suggest preferring it as it is quite colloquial to my ear.

`Заходи как-нибудь показать фотки!`
Sounds alright. Grammatically correct and as good as the {Imperative + Future} one.

> On another note: Is it unusual to use the perfective "зайти" here?

It is not unusual and completely correct but it sounds more 'demanding', if you're not very close with this person I wouldn't suggest using it.

Comment: There is a slightly different level of importance in the latter "показать" option vs others. The last phrase, with its ".....заходи ЧТОБЫ показать..." omitted implies that that showing of the photos is the sole or at least primary reason for the visit. It hints that the showing is so important per se that it alone warrants making the visit. While prior options downplay that importance, they ask to casually drop in, and then use that visit as an opportunity to show the photos among other activities. I agree that the difference is very small though, and practically all forms are interchangeable.

Answer (score 3):

All these sentences are valid meaning you invite someone to come to your place and show some pictures.

> 1. Заходи как-нибудь, покажешь фотки! {Imperative + Future} (come and you will/can show)
> 2. Заходи как-нибудь, покажи фотки! {Imperative + Imperative}(come and show)
>
> 3.Заходи как-нибудь показать фотки! {Imperative + Infinitive} (come in order to show--purpose )

And the same forms are valid with the perfective imperative as well,  with no difference in meaning.

> Зайди как-нибудь, покажешь фотки! Зайди как‐нибудь показать фотки. Зайди как‐нибудь, покажи фотки.

All are equally used, we don't have any preference.
Besides you can use different verbs in both parts.

> Приходи/приди/забеги/забегай/загляни/заскочи, etc.

Comment: Do you mean "milder " than "покажи"? Yes, I think so, but "не приглядишь"has got a negation,  that makes a soft, polite form.

Answer (score 1):

Приди - It is imperative within a non-strict sense of commanding (imperative) to do something. "Come to my house and show me.... blabla..."

Приходи- It is a no-deal strict order, but you can use it when you are confident to someone also, and you are eager and happy to see the other one that you can say "You will have come to my house" (Will have participle = Future Perfect) and as "Приходи" is perfective, then we can relate it to "**Future-Perfect-imperative**".

And you are a soldier, and you order.. you say "Приходи" and not "Приди"

You will have come (perfect future, no deal.. you have to) = Приходи
Future Perfect = Perfective

Hope it helps.